# Embed youtube list with sidemenu opened

Tags: youtube, playlist

I'm an editor in a wordpress blog I have embedded an youtube list with this code:

```
[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*********&list=**************************]
```

I want that the plalist has the sidemenu opened by defalut. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using the modern OEmbed method of just putting the URL on a line on its own? You don't need to use a shortcode to embed youtube videos

Comment: A quick google later and I don't believe this is either possible, or a WordPress question. What you want does not exist and will require changes to youtube.com to be possible. You will need to speak to Youtube dev support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, youtube doesn't provide an embed with an open playlist. If it did, this isn't something that could be resolved from the WordPress end, as it's a Youtube OEmbed issue.

You will need to refer to Youtube documentation or their support channels

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.